# Getting folder conflicts when running yum groupupdate inside a chroot environment

Tags: linux, centos7, rpm, yum, chroot

I have a chroot environment where i am getting folder conflicts when I am running the below command.

```
/usr/bin/yum --verbose --assumeyes --installroot /home/prateek/project/.ova_work_dir/mnt/dst_root --config=/home/prateek/project/.ova_work_dir/mnt/dst_root/etc/yum.repos.d/project-upgrade.repo --obsoletes groupupdate '*' project
```

Below is the error

```
Running transaction test

    Transaction check error:
      file /usr from install of messagebus_c-1.0.0-0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-20.el7.x86_64
```

I have below two questions to ask:

1) Why i am getting folder conflict when yum is running transaction test as I have seen file conflicts but not folder conflicts.

2) How would I resolve this folder conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

The `messagebus_c` RPM specfile needs to be edited to not "own" `/usr` but instead all the files in it, *e.g.* `/usr/*`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
/usr/bin/yum --verbose --assumeyes --installroot=/home/prateek/project/.ova_work_dir/mnt/dst_root --config=/home/prateek/project/.ova_work_dir/mnt/dst_root/etc/yum.repos.d/project-upgrade.repo --obsoletes groupupdate '*' project
```

issue was

missing equal to sign `--installroot /home`

expected like this    `--installroot=/home`

Comment: 1. can you download rpm manually ? and then try `rpm -qlp <path to rpm>`. for both the packages.

Comment: 2. I think messagebus_c is package built locally. if yes can you check rpmspec for  `%files` ?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when `messagebus_c` spec file has:

```
%install
touch %{buildroot}/usr

%files
/usr
```

I.e. here the `/usr` is a file. While `filesystem` provides it as a directory. You cannot have both. A directory cannot be a file. And vice versa.